# adding asp.net user control dynamically using Jquery problem

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-controls, dynamic

I am  adding asp.net user control through jquery on a button click in main form dynamically. i have successfully added that control to my main page. but issue is that my control contains a button in it and whenever i click on that button that cause the whole page to reload and hence my control is washed away.

can somebody tell me where am i going wrong and what i need to do.
i just need to perform certain actions on button click of the control. can i stop the page to reload or how can i render my control again in main page whenever page is refreshed??

thanx

Comment: Does it have to be a full blown asp.net control or can you use a normal html button and wire a jQuery event up to that instead?

Comment: Could you post some relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to reinitialize the control every time after a postback, using something like ScriptManager's [RegisterStartupScript()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx).